# Is unplugging computer power cable the same electricity outage?

Tags: power-supply

I am not sure if they are the same, but something puzzling just happened. My dell precision workstation 2007 has been fine ever since, with many, many power outages over the years. But there is a time a guy pulled the power cable off, and a few days later the PC no longer boot, with loud whooss fan sound at startup. After testing, everything was fine, only the motherboard died, with apparent fried capacitors.

Can anyone please explain? Thank you.

Comment: Even power outages could be very different (no voltage, low voltage, wrong frequency, …).

Comment: If the PC died "a few days later", the cable being pulled out was not the cause. The motherboard was dying for months already.

Comment: This might be more suited to https://electronics.stackexchange.com because it's more of a theoretical question about electronics than a computing problem

Comment: *"... and a few days later ..."* --  Seem like you insist on making a connection between events days apart rather than assume a coincidence.  *"After testing, everything was fine, ... with apparent fried capacitors."* -- What kind of *"testing"* and by whom?

Answer (score 0):

Cutting off power to PC can **not** damage the hardware. Only OS can be messed up, and unsaved data can be lost. The motherboard died for some other reason, and it would happen even if power cable was not unplugged.

Comment: This is only partially true. For example if the disconnection was not a clean break (think rapidly turning off and on and off again) it could have caused the components to draw more power then they otherwise would and it could be the straw that broke the camels back.

Comment: @davidgo Yes that would be problematic, but that is not what the OP descried. While PC is powering on capacitors are being charged from 0 charge and electric current is much higher than.

Answer (score 0):

@Zoran Jankov what if the power supply is very old like this one since 2007?

I have a theory. Even assuming the power supply is new and everything is functioning as expected from an international standard point of view, it might be still different if one unplugs the power cable from the PSU directly instead of from the wall outlet; there would be no different between unplugging the cable from the wall outlet and electricity outage because the current flowing/voltage is the same, unlike unplugging directly from the PSU where the current/voltage is halted immediately. And since the PSU is very old, its surge protection might not hold- result in short circuit? Possible?

#Daniel B exactly if you think in terms of micro nano level

Comment: Whether you pull the connector out of the PSU, or the connector at the wall socket, or even chop the cable in the middle with an axe, the result is exactly the same. The AC power stops.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I'm no expert but I don't agree. By pulling out the cord you are physically disconnecting live and neutral and removing any direct grounding - I don't see how that could happen during a typical power cut. I would expect this could affect how some of the capacitors discharge. Maybe if it was disconnected at the AC peak and the capacitors were left charged this would put extra strain on them, I really don't know but clearly it's complicated

Comment: I was disagreeing with simonv's assertion that it might make a difference whether the connector at the PSU end of the power lead was yanked out, or the one at the wall outlet. Regarding "grounding" in the electrical safety sense, removal of this from a PSU would have ne effect whatsoever on what happens to capacitors on the motherboard, which only "see" DC supplied by the PSU.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Yes I was thinking more about it potentially damaging the PSU than the motherboard but it sounds like that wasn't the case here. Whether or not disconnecting it like that could somehow translate to a surge on the DC output I don't know

Comment: If the cord was pulled out smartly I think it would probably have a similar effect to operating a double-pole AC power switch which most PSUs used to have. Of course with an aging motherboard with capacitor disease all bets are off. In the UK we have wall AC power outlets with switches and I invariably turn off mine at the wall when I go to bed each night. All of my PCs, routers, etc have been subjected to this and seem to suffer no ill effects.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, that's what I thought too, but electricity is a complex issue, it's like water flow. Do you think there's a difference if the PC is plugged into a power strip? I left out power strip to relax the issue. I think capacitors and surge protectors are the key to play here.

Comment: @JamesP Thank you for referring me to electronics.stackexchange.com. I will ask there too.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey *"capacitors on the motherboard, which only "see" DC supplied by the PSU"* -- That's too simplistic a view. There's a difference between a floating ground (i.e. unplugged) versus a ground that is still earthed (i.e. there's a path for current to dissipate).  That why the safe way to test a UPS is using the switch on a power strip rather than just pulling the plug.

Comment: How does electric current "dissipate" in these situations? What current?

Comment: @simonv -- Please take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and learn how to use these sites.  This is not a forum for a discussion.

Comment: @sawdust are you saying that I should not reply to any comment or limit my comments? It was tested by me by exchanging components of the same machine models. I've never ruled out the possibility of coincidence. The question is grounded on actual events, and if you think the question or event doesn't make any sense, maybe you have yet to experience yourself. Thank you and have a nice day.